# Converting byte[] to Pdf using C#

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, arrays

How to write byte[](Source file is word) value to pdf.

Here is the code which i am using.

```
FtpWebRequest reqFTP;

strPath="ftp://1.1.1.1/Docs/word.doc";
strFileName="output.doc";
FileStream outputStream = new FileStream("C:/folder/" + Session.SessionID + "/" + strFileName, FileMode.Create);


reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(strPath));
reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
reqFTP.UseBinary = true;

               
reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(strUname, strPassword);
reqFTP.Proxy = null;

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();

Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();


strExt = strFileName.Split('.');

               

long cl = response.ContentLength;
readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
while (readCount > 0)
{
    outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
    readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
}

ftpStream.Close();
outputStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

byte[] source comes from the FtpWebRequest.GetResponseStream() source is word file..How to write the byte[] to pdf file.

I have tried the way which mentioned in this link[Byte[] to Pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259121/byte-array-to-pdf),  but when i try to open pdf it showing (Adobe reader could not open. because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damanged(for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)).

Thank You

Comment: What you're actually asking is how to convert a .doc (contained in a byte[]) to a .pdf.  Do you have Microsoft Word installed on the computer this will be running on?

Comment: @Dan Field   Yes you are correct but Microsoft Word is not installed. Can we able to  convert a word (contained in a byte[])  to pdf document. without Microsoft Office.?

Comment: Rewrite your question to clarify, but you'll probably find that the only easy ways to do this involve expensive third party libraries, office to be installed, or using a web service to convert it for you.  The hard ways (doing more of it yourself) will require way more than a SO answer could supply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use third-party component for your perpose. like Aspose.Words. it can simplely do this work for you.